# Проблемы с Service android при попытке отправки GPS данных через DDMS

Tags: эмулятор, android, service

Доброго времени суток. Пишу программу на android которая в фоновом режиме определяет местоположение устройства и отправляет на сервер. Как минимальную sdk выбрал 8-ую (android 2.2),чтобы поддерживало как можно больше устройств. Все сделал все настроил , написал запустил, РАБОТАЕТ!!! Но только на андройдах 2.2 , 3.2 (4.0 не смотрел пока и не надо).
на 2.3.* запускается приложение, запускается сервис, но когда через DDMS отправляю координаты ничего не происходит, а через пару секунд эмулятор сам перезапускается или выдает ошибку. повторюсь что на других версиях работало, пробовал на другом компе запустить, то же самое. на реальном устройстве рога запускается, включается сервис, но не показывает местоположение не с gps не с network провайдером.
Подскажите пожалуйста ,что это может быть и что делать?
ниже прикреплю начало лога Logcat при умирании эмулятора, весь лог в конце вопроса. (спрятал бы под спойлер но не знаю как тут это сделать)

```
08-04 09:40:27.722: V/ru.bazanski.tracker.beta.Main_Activity(334): onClick: Starting service.
08-04 09:40:27.924: V/ru.bazanski.tracker.beta.ServiceGPS(334): запуск сервиса, интернет доступен
08-04 09:40:27.924: V/ru.bazanski.tracker.beta.ServiceGPS(334): gps
08-04 09:40:27.942: V/ru.bazanski.tracker.beta.ServiceGPS(334): AlarmManger started at 2012-08-04 09:40:27.945
08-04 09:40:27.942: V/ru.bazanski.tracker.beta.ServiceGPS(334): onCreate(..)
08-04 09:40:32.973: V/ru.bazanski.tracker.beta.RepeatingAlarmService(421): Timed alarm onReceive() started at time: 2012-08-04 09:40:32.979
08-04 09:40:38.737: I/DEBUG(30): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
08-04 09:40:38.737: I/DEBUG(30): Build fingerprint: 'generic/sdk/generic:2.3.3/GRI34/101070:eng/test-keys'
08-04 09:40:38.737: I/DEBUG(30): pid: 74, tid: 232  >>> system_server <<<
08-04 09:40:38.737: I/DEBUG(30): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000
08-04 09:40:38.737: I/DEBUG(30):  r0 00000000  r1 40940a80  r2 41ae0114  r3 46277c74
08-04 09:40:38.737: I/DEBUG(30):  r4 00000138  r5 00000000  r6 40940a80  r7 41ae0114
08-04 09:40:38.737: I/DEBUG(30):  r8 80701321  r9 80702240  10 00100000  fp 00000001
08-04 09:40:38.737: I/DEBUG(30):  ip ae20e7ec  sp 46277c60  lr ae20acd7  pc ae207dfe  cpsr 00000030
08-04 09:40:38.983: I/DEBUG(30):          #00  pc 00007dfe  /system/lib/libandroid_servers.so
08-04 09:40:38.983: I/DEBUG(30):          #01  pc 0000acd2  /system/lib/libandroid_servers.so
08-04 09:40:38.983: I/DEBUG(30):          #02  pc 000012ca  /system/lib/hw/gps.goldfish.so
08-04 09:40:38.983: I/DEBUG(30):          #03  pc 000014ae  /system/lib/hw/gps.goldfish.so
08-04 09:40:38.983: I/DEBUG(30):          #04  pc 00011a7c  /system/lib/libc.so
08-04 09:40:38.994: I/DEBUG(30):          #05  pc 00011640  /system/lib/libc.so
08-04 09:40:38.994: I/DEBUG(30): code around pc:
08-04 09:40:38.994: I/DEBUG(30): ae207ddc ab04b082 9301cb04 6f646804 b00247a0 
08-04 09:40:38.994: I/DEBUG(30): ae207dec bc08bc10 4718b002 b510b40c ab04b082 
08-04 09:40:38.994: I/DEBUG(30): ae207dfc 6804cb04 34f89301 47a06824 bc10b002 
08-04 09:40:38.994: I/DEBUG(30): ae207e0c b002bc08 46c04718 b510b40c ab04b082 
08-04 09:40:38.994: I/DEBUG(30): ae207e1c 9301cb04 34986804 47a06824 bc10b002 
08-04 09:40:38.994: I/DEBUG(30): code around lr:
08-04 09:40:38.994: I/DEBUG(30): ae20acb4 91099008 f7fb6aa0 900aeab6 1c3a910b 
08-04 09:40:39.003: I/DEBUG(30): ae20acc4 6b646b23 930c1c28 1c31940d f7fd9b0f 
08-04 09:40:39.003: I/DEBUG(30): ae20acd4 4906f88f 44791c28 f7ff3150 b011fe1d 
08-04 09:40:39.003: I/DEBUG(30): ae20ace4 46c0bdf0 000043cc 00004148 00000786 
08-04 09:40:39.003: I/DEBUG(30): ae20acf4 f7fbb510 bd10ec24 4802b510 f7fb4478 
08-04 09:40:39.003: I/DEBUG(30): stack:
08-04 09:40:39.003: I/DEBUG(30):     46277c20  d97f62b7  
08-04 09:40:39.003: I/DEBUG(30):     46277c24  40c7d685  
08-04 09:40:39.003: I/DEBUG(30):     46277c28  0000000a  
08-04 09:40:39.003: I/DEBUG(30):     46277c2c  00000000  
08-04 09:40:39.003: I/DEBUG(30):     46277c30  0000ab90  [heap]
08-04 09:40:39.003: I/DEBUG(30):     46277c34  80048c1b  /system/lib/libdvm.so
08-04 09:40:39.003: I/DEBUG(30):     46277c38  0000ab90  [heap]
08-04 09:40:39.013: I/DEBUG(30):     46277c3c  46277c6c  
08-04 09:40:39.013: I/DEBUG(30):     46277c40  00010004  [heap]
08-04 09:40:39.013: I/DEBUG(30):     46277c44  80037667  /system/lib/libdvm.so
08-04 09:40:39.013: I/DEBUG(30):     46277c48  00000000  
08-04 09:40:39.013: I/DEBUG(30):     46277c4c  afd0dcc4  /system/lib/libc.so
08-04 09:40:39.013: I/DEBUG(30):     46277c50  00000000  
08-04 09:40:39.013: I/DEBUG(30):     46277c54  46277e00  
08-04 09:40:39.013: I/DEBUG(30):     46277c58  df002777  
08-04 09:40:39.013: I/DEBUG(30):     46277c5c  e3a070ad  
08-04 09:40:39.013: I/DEBUG(30): #00 46277c60  00000001  
08-04 09:40:39.013: I/DEBUG(30):     46277c64  ad331275  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
08-04 09:40:39.013: I/DEBUG(30):     46277c68  00000138  
08-04 09:40:39.013: I/DEBUG(30):     46277c6c  ae20acd7  /system/lib/libandroid_servers.so
08-04 09:40:39.023: I/DEBUG(30):     46277c70  41ae0114  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
08-04 09:40:39.023: I/DEBUG(30):     46277c74  00000003  
08-04 09:40:39.023: I/DEBUG(30): #01 46277c78  4284dfce  /data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@framework.jar@classes.dex
08-04 09:40:39.023: I/DEBUG(30):     46277c7c  4042b604  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
08-04 09:40:39.023: I/DEBUG(30):     46277c80  cffeb075  
08-04 09:40:39.023: I/DEBUG(30):     46277c84  c05e8561  
08-04 09:40:39.023: I/DEBUG(30):     46277c88  00000000  
08-04 09:40:39.023: I/DEBUG(30):     46277c8c  00000000  
08-04 09:40:39.023: I/DEBUG(30):     46277c90  00000000  
08-04 09:40:39.023: I/DEBUG(30):     46277c94  00000000  
08-04 09:40:39.023: I/DEBUG(30):     46277c98  00000000  
08-04 09:40:39.023: I/DEBUG(30):     46277c9c  00000000  
08-04 09:40:39.023: I/DEBUG(30):     46277ca0  00000000  
08-04 09:40:39.023: I/DEBUG(30):     46277ca4  00000000  
08-04 09:40:39.023: I/DEBUG(30):     46277ca8  eeee7000  
08-04 09:40:39.023: I/DEBUG(30):     46277cac  00000138  
08-04 09:40:39.023: I/DEBUG(30):     46277cb0  46277e56  
08-04 09:40:39.023: I/DEBUG(30):     46277cb4  00000003  
08-04 09:40:39.023: I/DEBUG(30):     46277cb8  0000000a  
08-04 09:40:39.033: I/DEBUG(30):     46277cbc  46277de8  
08-04 09:40:39.033: I/DEBUG(30):     46277cc0  00000000  
08-04 09:40:39.033: I/DEBUG(30):     46277cc4  46277e6c  
08-04 09:40:39.033: I/DEBUG(30):     46277cc8  00000001  
08-04 09:40:39.033: I/DEBUG(30):     46277ccc  807012cd  /system/lib/hw/gps.goldfish.so
08-04 09:40:42.953: V/ru.bazanski.tracker.beta.RepeatingAlarmService(421): Timed alarm onReceive() started at time: 2012-08-04 09:40:42.956
08-04 09:40:50.343: D/Zygote(32): Process 74 terminated by signal (11)
08-04 09:40:50.343: I/Zygote(32): Exit zygote because system server (74) has terminated
08-04 09:40:50.383: I/ActivityThread(195): Removing dead content provider: settings
08-04 09:40:50.383: I/ActivityThread(272): Removing dead content provider: settings
08-04 09:40:50.383: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'usagestats' died
08-04 09:40:50.383: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'audio' died
08-04 09:40:50.383: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'uimode' died
08-04 09:40:50.383: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'backup' died
08-04 09:40:50.383: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'diskstats' died
08-04 09:40:50.383: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'meminfo' died
08-04 09:40:50.383: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'cpuinfo' died
08-04 09:40:50.383: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'permission' died
08-04 09:40:50.383: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'SurfaceFlinger' died
08-04 09:40:50.383: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'batteryinfo' died
08-04 09:40:50.383: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'sensorservice' died
08-04 09:40:50.383: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'entropy' died
08-04 09:40:50.383: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'power' died
08-04 09:40:50.383: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'telephony.registry' died
08-04 09:40:50.383: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'package' died
08-04 09:40:50.383: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'activity' died
08-04 09:40:50.383: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'account' died
08-04 09:40:50.383: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'content' died
08-04 09:40:50.383: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'appwidget' died
08-04 09:40:50.383: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'hardware' died
08-04 09:40:50.383: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'battery' died
08-04 09:40:50.383: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'vibrator' died
08-04 09:40:50.383: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'alarm' died
08-04 09:40:50.383: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'window' died
08-04 09:40:50.383: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'statusbar' died
08-04 09:40:50.383: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'clipboard' died
08-04 09:40:50.383: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'device_policy' died
08-04 09:40:50.383: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'input_method' died
08-04 09:40:50.383: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'netstat' died
08-04 09:40:50.383: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'network_management' died
08-04 09:40:50.393: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'wifi' died
08-04 09:40:50.393: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'connectivity' died
08-04 09:40:50.393: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'throttle' died
08-04 09:40:50.393: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'accessibility' died
08-04 09:40:50.393: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'mount' died
08-04 09:40:50.393: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'notification' died
08-04 09:40:50.393: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'devicestoragemonitor' died
08-04 09:40:50.393: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'location' died
08-04 09:40:50.393: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'search' died
08-04 09:40:50.393: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'dropbox' died
08-04 09:40:50.393: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'wallpaper' died
08-04 09:40:50.403: I/ActivityThread(334): Removing dead content provider: settings
08-04 09:40:50.403: I/ActivityThread(234): Removing dead content provider: settings
08-04 09:40:50.403: I/ActivityThread(229): Removing dead content provider: settings
08-04 09:40:50.403: I/ActivityThread(167): Removing dead content provider: settings
08-04 09:40:50.403: I/ActivityThread(165): Removing dead content provider: settings
08-04 09:40:50.426: I/ActivityThread(157): Removing dead content provider: settings
08-04 09:40:50.426: E/installd(34): eof
08-04 09:40:50.426: E/installd(34): failed to read size
08-04 09:40:50.426: I/installd(34): closing connection
08-04 09:40:50.437: D/qemud(37): fdhandler_event: disconnect on fd 11
08-04 09:40:50.467: E/InputQueue-JNI(167): channel '406ba6f0 StatusBar (client)' ~ Publisher closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
08-04 09:40:50.473: E/InputQueue-JNI(167): channel '4076abf0 TrackingView (client)' ~ Publisher closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
08-04 09:40:50.473: E/InputQueue-JNI(167): channel '4077b728 StatusBarExpanded (client)' ~ Publisher closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
08-04 09:40:50.473: E/InputQueue-JNI(234): channel '4076ec80 com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher (client)' ~ Publisher closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
08-04 09:40:50.473: E/InputQueue-JNI(334): channel '40915ad8 ru.bazanski.tracker.beta/ru.bazanski.tracker.beta.Main_Activity (client)' ~ Publisher closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
08-04 09:40:50.743: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'media.audio_flinger' died
08-04 09:40:50.743: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'media.audio_policy' died
08-04 09:40:50.743: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'media.player' died
08-04 09:40:50.743: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'media.camera' died
08-04 09:40:50.914: I/Netd(451): Netd 1.0 starting
08-04 09:40:51.053: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'isms' died
08-04 09:40:51.053: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'simphonebook' died
08-04 09:40:51.053: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'iphonesubinfo' died
08-04 09:40:51.053: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'phone' died
08-04 09:40:52.253: D/AndroidRuntime(452): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit <<<<<<
08-04 09:40:52.263: D/AndroidRuntime(452): CheckJNI is ON
08-04 09:40:52.833: I/(450): ServiceManager: 0xad50
08-04 09:40:52.854: D/AudioHardwareInterface(450): setMode(NORMAL)
08-04 09:40:52.873: I/CameraService(450): CameraService started (pid=450)
08-04 09:40:52.903: I/AudioFlinger(450): AudioFlinger's thread 0xc658 ready to run
08-04 09:40:53.654: I/SamplingProfilerIntegration(452): Profiler is disabled.
08-04 09:40:53.784: I/Zygote(452): Preloading classes...
```

весь лог тут [DDMS_log](http://yadi.sk/d/O4BGIs_N308X)

П.С.
избавился от проблемы когда изменил target sdk c target=android-8 на target=Google Inc.:Google APIs:8 в файле project.properties
теперь на эмуле не рушится при обновлении координат, но дело в том что теперь для запуска нужен эмуль google api 10, а не 2.3.3 api 10.
Поэтому я проверил стурую версию которая рушилась на эмуле google api 10 и о чудо, оно не умерло, выходит что проблема именно в эмуляторе 2.3.3, я обновил все компоненты разработки под android, ситуация не изменилась. На реальном устройстве с андройд 2.3.4 данные место положения не обновляются, сервис работает но ничего не делает, вне зависимости от значения target= в файле project.properties, когда как на 3.2 планшете все хорошо работает. Прошу помочь.

Comment: Где-то идет обращение к неинциализированному сегменту памяти.
Ищите на [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=signal+11) ваш вариант, или может какой-то из ответов натолкнет на мысль. В любом случае, нужно локализовать ошибку...

Comment: Но почему тогда та же самая программа нормально работает на других версиях андрюши?

Comment: Ну это нормальная ситуация, попробуйте на 4-ке проверить тоже, если ошибка сохранится, значит в любом случае исправлять придется.

Comment: В том то и дело, что мне надо, чтобы на 2.3 работало 100%. Буду думать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ нашел, проблема в том что в используемой мной на тот момент android sdk был неисправный эмулятор android 2.3.3